# How to replace columns with respect to column names?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, loops

Let's consider two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 1, 2), 
                  "B" = 2:4,
                  "C" = 3:5,
                  "D" = 1:3)

> df1
  A B C D
1 1 2 3 1
2 1 3 4 2
3 2 4 5 3

df2 <- data.frame("A_log" = log(c(1, 1, 2)),
                  "C_diff" = diff(c(2,4,1,7)),
                  "C_log" = log(3:5))

> df2
       A_log C_diff    C_log
1 0.0000000      2 1.098612
2 0.0000000     -3 1.386294
3 0.6931472      6 1.609438
```

I want to replace columns of `df1` with columns from `df2` in the way following - column names of `df2` are transformed column names of `df1` (always column name of `df2` is in format `df1.colname_something`).
So I want to replace columns from df1 by columns from df2 which column names are modified. For example:
Column "A" should be replaced by A_log (same column name and added `_log`). Now we want to replace column "C" in df1, and since we have two columns starting from "C" in `df2` then we will replace one column "C" in `df1` with two columns from `df2`. We don't replace column `"B"` and `"D"` because there is no variable starting from those letters in `df2`

i.e. I want to have an output:

```
       Alog B C_diff    C_log D
1 0.0000000 2      2 1.098612 1
2 0.0000000 3     -3 1.386294 2
3 0.6931472 4      6 1.609438 3
```

**My work so far**

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(df1))) {
  # Obtain next column names of df1
  df1.colname <- colnames(df1)[i]
  # Compare patterns of df1.colname with df2 column names and look for similarities.
  which_match <- which(grepl(df1.colname, colnames(df2)))
  if (length(which_match) >= 1) {
    df3 <- cbind(df3, df2[which_match])
  }
  else {
    df3 <- cbind(df3, df1[i])
  }
}

> df3[, -1]
       A_log B C_diff    C_log D
1 0.0000000 2      2 1.098612 1
2 0.0000000 3     -3 1.386294 2
3 0.6931472 4      6 1.609438 3
```

And this solution is quite good in my opinion - for sure it's working. The big drawback of it is that it's using loop which is may not be necessary in this case. Do you think that maybe there is some other better approach to do that, or maybe the loop is avoidable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df2` as it is and select columns from `df1` whose subset is not present in `df2`.

```
cbind(df2, df1[setdiff(names(df1), sub('_.*', '', names(df2)))])

#      A_log C_diff    C_log B D
#1 0.0000000      2 1.098612 2 1
#2 0.0000000     -3 1.386294 3 2
#3 0.6931472      6 1.609438 4 3
```

`sub('_.*', '', names(df2))` part might be specific to the column names in your actual dataset. In the example, the pattern that you have is `ColumnNameFromdf1_somethingelse` so I remove `_somethingelse` from the column name keeping only the part which is available in `df1` hence here it returns.

```
sub('_.*', '', names(df2))
#[1] "A" "C" "C"
```

Comment: Hey Ronak! Thank you very much for your anwer! The only problem I have with your solution is that you arrange your columns differently. First columns you have are transformed columns `("A_log", "C_diff", "C_log")` and then non-transformed `("B" , "D")`. 
If you have a look at output I got, it's something I'm looking for i.e. the variables layout doesn't change (still B is after A)

Comment: If you store the output from `cbind` in `result`. You can do `result[gtools::mixedsort(names(result))]` to get the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going over each `name` of *df1*, search for the name in *df2* using `grep` and if found return those form *df2* otherwise the one form *df1*.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(names(df1), function(x) {
  i <- grep(paste0("^", x, "_"), names(df2))
  if(length(i) > 0) df2[i]
  else df1[x]
}))
#      A_log B C_diff    C_log D
#1 0.0000000 2      2 1.098612 1
#2 0.0000000 3     -3 1.386294 2
#3 0.6931472 4      6 1.609438 3
```